# How to convert excel string to formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I developed a spreadsheet with many formulas and sent it to a colleague whose firewall policy prohibits excel formulas. (Don't ask). So using search and replace, I prepended all the equals signs with apostrophes. So that `=CCONCATENATE(A1,A2)`became `'=CONCATENATE(A1, A2)`. Although the firewall let the file pass, we're not having an easy time reversing the process.  Search doesn't find the leading apostrophe.  Attempts to escape the apostrophe, or to use `CHAR(39)`to remove it have proved unsuccessful. Thanks for any help!

Comment: use another character(s) instead of `'`. E.g. `#trickWirewall#` will also corrupt the formula and it's easy to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this short macro will restore all your formulas:

```
Sub RestoreFormulas()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Left(r.Value, 1) = "=" Then r.Formula = r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Wait, so they allow macros, but not formulas? That's quite silly.

Comment: No, they don't allow macros. But after the spreadsheet has passed through the FW, this macro can be used to remove the leading apostrophes.